# Genesis Config of ORML tokens not loaded for other pallets

Tags: token, orml

In my runtime, one pallet reserves some currency using the `orml-currencies` pallet on genesis, and for this, it depends on accounts having some initial balance. This should be provided by the genesis config of the `orml-tokens` module

For reference, this is my genesis config for the `orml-tokens` module

```rs
//<snip>
        tokens: parachain_template_runtime::TokensConfig {
            balances: endowed_accounts
            .iter()
            .flat_map(|x| {
                vec![
                    (x.clone(), CurrencyId::DOT, ENDOWMENT),
                    (x.clone(), CurrencyId::BTC, ENDOWMENT),
                ]
            })
            .collect(),
            
        },
//<snip>
```

And my runtime config for `orml-currencies`

```rs
//<snip>
parameter_types! {
    pub const GetNativeCurrencyId: CurrencyId = CurrencyId::Native;
}

impl orml_currencies::Config for Runtime {
    type MultiCurrency = Tokens;
    type NativeCurrency = BasicCurrencyAdapter<Runtime, Balances, Amount, BlockNumber>;
    type GetNativeCurrencyId = GetNativeCurrencyId;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
//<snip>
```

When I set the currencyId of the genesis run of the extrinsic to Native, the reserve works.

Strangely, when I use a different currencyId, the reserve doesn't work. The extrinsic throws an "InsufficientBalance" Error.

To take things further, when I try the exact same extrinsic after genesis with a new account that's funded with some currency (e.g DOT) by one of the accounts intialised on genesis, the extrinsic works